# android - SQL database, how can I make my code more efficient

Tags: android, database, android-cursor, android-database

I'm running a SQL query in a Database helper class method to return all entries from "drugs" table

```
list_all_drugs() {
  Cursor cursor = db.query("drugs", null , null, null, null, null, null);
  return cursor;
}
```

then in my activity I use the cursor data as the following :

```
db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    c = db.list_all_drugs();
    c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        viewDrug(c.getString(0),c.getString(1),c.getString(2),c.getString(3),c.getString(4),c.getString(5),c.getString(6),c.getString(7),c.getString(8),c.getString(9),c.getString(10),c.getString(11));
        c.moveToNext();
}
```

then I pass these parameters to the viewDrug() method to display list of drugs from the database. Every thing is working fine, but I find this method not the best practice (?) specially when I want to insert or delete a database column the whole code structure would fail and I would have to do much hard coding.

So, in short, is there a better approach to dynamically interact with database columns rather than calling them one by one using their indexes ? thanks.

Comment: Unless you would like to use some ORM, then you'll need to use column indices at some point

Comment: check these libs https://android-arsenal.com/tag/25

Comment: `"then I pass these parameters to the viewDrug() method to display list of drugs from the database"` where do you want to display them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to declare all column name with static final variables like this example:

```
public static final String TABLE_DRUGS = "drugs";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "Name";
public static final String COLUMN_DOSAGE = "Dosage";
```

Then get your cursor value using Cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME) and Cursor.getString like this:

```
c.moveToFirst();
  while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
    HashMap <String,String> columnsValues = new HashMap<>();
    columnsValues.put(COLUMN_NAME, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)));
    columnsValues.put(COLUMN_DOSAGE, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DOSAGE)));
    viewDrug(columnsValues);
    c.moveToNext();
}
c.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I reached a partial solution. I didn't hear before about the cursor method `getColumnCount()` so I used it together with `HashMap` and a `for` loop to get the job done. Using the `HashMap` allows me to pass it over to other activity or fragment then get the column value using its name as a HashMap key

Here is my current code

```
c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        HashMap <String,String> columnsValues = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < c.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            columnsValues.put(c.getColumnName(i), c.getString(i));
        }
        viewDrug(columnsValues);
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    c.close();
```

I would still love to see any better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should get familiar with DAO Pattern to improve efficience for your code.

DAO pattern is very useful when interact with database. Easy to modify and create scalable system.

Follow this tutorial and practice with it.

[DAO Pattern Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm)

Hope it help !